# Does question age trump answer quality when it comes to duplication?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

As part of a bigger cleanup of the Logitech tag I stumbled across these two questions:

- [Is there a 64-bit Windows 7 driver for a Logitech Wingman Formula Force wheel?](https://superuser.com/questions/75775/is-there-a-64-bit-windows-7-driver-for-a-logitech-wingman-formula-force-wheel)

  - asked: 4 years ago
  - viewed: 15921 times
  - Answers: 3 (2, 0 and 0 upvotes)
- [How do I get the Logitech wingman formula force to work in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/253143/how-do-i-get-the-logitech-wingman-formula-force-to-work-in-windows-7)

  - asked: 3 years ago
  - viewed: 14838 times
  - Answers: 1 (6 upvotes)

The younger one has a better answer, compared to the direct link-only answer on the older one. Despite being asked about a year apart, there's only about 1000 views difference between them.

Based on these observations, I flagged the older as a duplicate of the younger (I don't have direct close vote privileges yet). I took the age into consideration when flagging the duplicate, but ultimately decided to flag in favour of the (IMHO) better question/answer.

Was this the correct call? Note that the OP of the older question thinks it should be [the other way around.](https://superuser.com/questions/75775/is-there-a-64-bit-windows-7-driver-for-a-logitech-wingman-formula-force-wheel#comment1086060_75775)

Comment: When you flag a question, a mod can choose to merge answers if they feel it is appropriate. It should be sufficient to flag either one.

Comment: So you're saying I should Flag->Mod Attention instead of Flag->Duplicate?

Comment: Ironically [DUPE!](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6924/should-older-questions-be-flagged-as-duplicates-of-more-recent-ones-if-those-hav?rq=1)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - lol :P. Thanks, that answers my point

Comment: That is is some meta-meta closing...sorry about the dupe trump!